# Spring Cloud Stream send/consume message to different partitions with KafkaHeaders.Message_KEY

Tags: java, apache-kafka, jhipster, spring-cloud-stream

```
I am trying to implement a prototype for implementing messaging system using Spring Cloud Stream. I selected Apache Kafka as binder. I created a topic with 2 partitions for scalability.  Then I tried to  send different messages to different partitions using following rest api method.
```

I set 2 different message keys for 2 partitions .

```
@PostMapping("/publish")
public void publish(@RequestParam String message) {
    log.debug("REST request the message : {} to send to Kafka topic ", message);
    Message message1 = MessageBuilder.withPayload("Hello from a")
        .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY, "node1")
        .build();
    Message message2 = MessageBuilder.withPayload("Hello from b")
        .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY, "node1")
        .build();
    Message message3 = MessageBuilder.withPayload("Hello from c")
        .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY, "node1")
        .build();
    Message message4 = MessageBuilder.withPayload("Hello from d")
        .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY, "node2")
        .build();
    Message message5 = MessageBuilder.withPayload("Hello from e")
        .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY, "node2")
        .build();
    Message message6 = MessageBuilder.withPayload("Hello from f")
        .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY, "node2")
        .build();
    output.send("simulatePf-out-0", message1);
    output.send("simulatePf-out-0", message2);
    output.send("simulatePf-out-0", message3);
    output.send("simulatePf-out-0", message4);
    output.send("simulatePf-out-0", message5);
    output.send("simulatePf-out-0", message6);


}
```

This is my application.yml for producer application

```
  cloud:
stream:
  kafka:
    binder:
      replicationFactor: 2
      auto-create-topics: true
      brokers: localhost:9092,localhost:9093,localhost:9094
      auto-add-partitions: true
    bindings:
      simulatePf-out-0:
        producer:
          configuration:
            key.serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
            value.serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
  bindings:
    simulatePf-out-0:
      producer:
        useNativeEncoding: true
        partition-count: 3
      destination: pf-topic
      content-type: text/plain
      group: dsa-back-end
```

To test parallelism, I created a consumer application that reads messages from pf-topic. This is configuration from consumer application.

```
  cloud:
stream:
  kafka:
    binder:
      replicationFactor: 2
      auto-create-topics: true
      brokers: localhost:9092, localhost:9093, localhost:9094
      min-partition-count: 2
    bindings:
      simulatePf-in-0:
          consumer:
              configuration:
                key.deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
                value.deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer

  bindings:
    simulatePf-in-0:
      destination: pf-topic
      content-type: text/plain
      group: powerflowservice
      consumer:
        use-native-decoding: true
```

.
I created a function in consumer application to consume messages

```
   @Bean
public Consumer<Message> simulatePf() {
    return message -> {
        log.info("header " + message.getHeaders());
        log.info("received " + message.getPayload());
    };
}
```

Now it is time for testing. To test parallelism, I run 2 instances of spring boot consumer application . I was expecting to see one consumer consumes messages from one partition, other consumer consumer messages from other partition. So I expect that message a, message b, message is consumed by consumer one. Message d, message e and message f is consumer by other consumer. Because I set different message keys to assign different partitions. But all messages are consumed by only one application

```
 2022-06-30 20:34:48.895  INFO 11860 --- [container-0-C-1] c.s.powerflow.config.AsyncConfiguration  : header {deliveryAttempt=1, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedMessageKey=node1, kafka_receivedTopic=pf-topic, skip-input-type-conversion=true, kafka_offset=270, scst_nativeHeadersPresent=true, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@1eaf51df, source-type=streamBridge, id=a77d12f2-f184-0f2f-6a76-147803dd43f3, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1656610488838, kafka_groupId=powerflowservice, timestamp=1656610488890}
2022-06-30 20:34:48.901  INFO 11860 --- [container-0-C-1] c.s.powerflow.config.AsyncConfiguration  : received Hello from a
2022-06-30 20:34:48.929  INFO 11860 --- [container-0-C-1] c.s.powerflow.config.AsyncConfiguration  : header {deliveryAttempt=1, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedMessageKey=node1, kafka_receivedTopic=pf-topic, skip-input-type-conversion=true, kafka_offset=271, scst_nativeHeadersPresent=true, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@1eaf51df, source-type=streamBridge, id=2e89f9b7-b6e7-482f-3c46-f73b2ad0705c, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1656610488840, kafka_groupId=powerflowservice, timestamp=1656610488929}
2022-06-30 20:34:48.932  INFO 11860 --- [container-0-C-1] c.s.powerflow.config.AsyncConfiguration  : received Hello from b
2022-06-30 20:34:48.933  INFO 11860 --- [container-0-C-1] c.s.powerflow.config.AsyncConfiguration  : header {deliveryAttempt=1, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedMessageKey=node1, kafka_receivedTopic=pf-topic, skip-input-type-conversion=true, kafka_offset=272, scst_nativeHeadersPresent=true, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@1eaf51df, source-type=streamBridge, id=15640532-b57f-b58e-62e7-c2bc9375fdf0, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1656610488841, kafka_groupId=powerflowservice, timestamp=1656610488933}
2022-06-30 20:34:48.934  INFO 11860 --- [container-0-C-1] c.s.powerflow.config.AsyncConfiguration  : received Hello from c
2022-06-30 20:34:48.935  INFO 11860 --- [container-0-C-1] c.s.powerflow.config.AsyncConfiguration  : header {deliveryAttempt=1, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedMessageKey=node2, kafka_receivedTopic=pf-topic, skip-input-type-conversion=true, kafka_offset=273, scst_nativeHeadersPresent=true, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@1eaf51df, source-type=streamBridge, id=590f0fb7-042f-e134-d214-ead570e42fe3, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1656610488842, kafka_groupId=powerflowservice, timestamp=1656610488934}
2022-06-30 20:34:48.938  INFO 11860 --- [container-0-C-1] c.s.powerflow.config.AsyncConfiguration  : received Hello from d
2022-06-30 20:34:48.940  INFO 11860 --- [container-0-C-1] c.s.powerflow.config.AsyncConfiguration  : header {deliveryAttempt=1, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedMessageKey=node2, kafka_receivedTopic=pf-topic, skip-input-type-conversion=true, kafka_offset=274, scst_nativeHeadersPresent=true, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@1eaf51df, source-type=streamBridge, id=9a67e68b-95d4-a02e-cc14-ac30c684b639, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1656610488842, kafka_groupId=powerflowservice, timestamp=1656610488940}
2022-06-30 20:34:48.941  INFO 11860 --- [container-0-C-1] c.s.powerflow.config.AsyncConfiguration  : received Hello from e
2022-06-30 20:34:48.943  INFO 11860 --- [container-0-C-1] c.s.powerflow.config.AsyncConfiguration  : header {deliveryAttempt=1, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedMessageKey=node2, kafka_receivedTopic=pf-topic, skip-input-type-conversion=true, kafka_offset=275, scst_nativeHeadersPresent=true, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@1eaf51df, source-type=streamBridge, id=333269af-bbd5-12b0-09de-8bd7959ebf08, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1656610488843, kafka_groupId=powerflowservice, timestamp=1656610488943}
2022-06-30 20:34:48.943  INFO 11860 --- [container-0-C-1] c.s.powerflow.config.AsyncConfiguration  : received Hello from f
```

Could you help me what I am missing.

Comment: Looks to me like your topic only has one partition, or your keys were all hashed into the same partition from the producer. You can use `kafka-consumer-groups --describe` to see what consumers are assigned what partitions

Comment: No. It has 3 partitions
 Topic: pf-topic Partition: 0    Leader: 3       Replicas: 3,1   Isr: 3,1
        Topic: pf-topic Partition: 1    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2   Isr: 1,2
        Topic: pf-topic Partition: 2    Leader: 2       Replicas: 2,3   Isr: 2,3

Comment: Okay, well, it's still possible that two keys can have the same hash, so end up in the same partition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only setting the message key as a header when you are sending. You can add the `KafkaHeaders.PARTITION` header on the message to force a specific partition.

If you don't want to add a hard-coded partition through the header, you can set a partition key SpEL expression or a partition key extractor bean in your application. Both of these mechanisms are Spring Cloud Stream specific. If you provide either of these, you still need to tell Spring Cloud Stream how you want to select the partition. For that, you can use a partition selector SpEL expression or a Partition Selector strategy. If you don't provide them, then it will use a default selector strategy by taking the `hashCode` of the message key % number of topic partitions.

I think you asked another related question yesterday and I linked this [blog](https://spring.io/blog/2021/02/03/demystifying-spring-cloud-stream-producers-with-apache-kafka-partitions) in my answer. In the last sections of that blog, all these details are explained.

Quoting from the blog:

> If you don’t provide a partition key expression or partition key extractor bean, then Spring Cloud Stream will completely stay out of the business of making any partition decision for you. In that case, if the topic has more than one partition, Kafka’s default partitioning mechanisms will be triggered. By default, Kafka uses a DefaultPartitioner, which if the message has a key (see above), then using the hash of this key for computing the partition.

I think you are seeing Kafka's default behavior in your application.